# Is it possible to set the different height for the treetable lines?

Tags: javascript, html, css, tree, webix

Trying to get this with the Webix Treetable. I can only set fixed `rowHeight` property. So here I face two problems:

- Height of the rows
- Position of the 'plus' icons (always on top)

Current treetable config is

```
rowHeight:100, rowLineHeight:34,
  columns:[{ 
    id:"value", 
    template:"{common.treetable()} #value#", 
    fillspace:true 
}],
```

Code sample: http://webix.com/snippet/23a6b79f

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the $height attribute in data, like in example. 
If you load data remotly, you can obviously pass it.

```
webix.ui({
  view:"treetable",
  rowHeight:100, rowLineHeight:34,
  columns:[{ 
    id:"value", 
    template:"{common.treetable()} #value#", 
    fillspace:true 
  }],    
  data: [{ 
    id:1,
    $height:30,
    value:"Root", 
    open:true, 
    data:[{ 
      id:"11", 
      value:"Text 1<br>Text 2<br>Text 3",
      data:[
        { id:"111", value:"Should be small too", $height:30}
      ]
    }]
  }]
});
```

http://webix.com/snippet/59a17d61

Comment: You have to also remove rowHeight and rowLineHeight